# Dynamic Streams Topology in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

While creating Kafka Streams using Kafka Streams DSL
https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/developer-guide

we have encountered a scenario where we need to update the Kafka Streams with new topology definition.

For example:
When we started, we have a topology defined to read from one topic (Source) and a destination topic (Sink).
However, on a configuration change we now need to read from 2 different topics (2 sources if you will) and write to a single destination topic.

From what we have built right now, the topology definition is hard coded, something like defined in [processor topology](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/developer-guide#streams_processor_topology).

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to define topology in a declarative way (say in a Json or something else), which doesn't require a codification of the topology?
2. Is it possible to reload an existing Kafka Stream to use a new definition of the Kafka Streams Topology?
3. For #2 mentioned above, does Kafka Streams DSL provide a way to "reload" new topology definitions by way of an external trigger or system call?

We are using JDK 1.8 and Kafka DSL 2.2.0

Thanks,
Ayusman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to define topology in a declarative way (say in a Json or something else), which doesn't require a codification of the topology?

The KStreams DSL is declarative, but I assume you mean something other than the DSL?

If so, the answer is No. You may want to look at KSQL, however.

> Is it possible to reload an existing Kafka Stream to use a new definition of the Kafka Streams Topology?

You mean if an existing Kafka Streams *application* can reload a new definition of a processing topology?  If so, the answer is No. In such cases, you'd deploy a new version of your application.

Depending on how the old/new topologies are defined, a simple rolling upgrade of your application may suffice (roughly: if the topology change was minimal), but probably you will need to deploy the new application separately and then, once the new one is vetted, decommission your old application.

Note: KStreams is a Java library and, by design, does not include functionality to operate/manage the Java applications that use the KStreams library.

> For #2 mentioned above, does Kafka Streams DSL provide a way to "reload" new topology definitions by way of an external trigger or system call?

No.

Comment: Hey @Michael G. Noll you are from Confluent like your profile suggests. Your presentation on "Introducing Kafka Streams" was informative. Thanks.